# Monitoring event log

Tags: c#, event-handling, event-log

I have a question about how things are going on under the hood with this in C#. If I have some code like this:

```
// Create the event log monitor
eventLog.Log = eventLogToMonitor;
eventLog.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
eventLog.EntryWritten += new EntryWrittenEventHandler(EventLogMonitor);
```

Does .NET set up its own thread to monitor the event log for entries written, or how does it now that this event has happened?

Comment: I have used WMI in the past to wire up events and monitor the EventLog. have you attempted a google search for this "Monitoring Event Log"

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with things like "C# .NET". That's what we use tags for on [so].

Comment: @JohnSaunders Please don't link to a site we are already on. Why not link to at minimum the [tags](http://stackoverflow.com/tags) area within stackoverflow which provides a brief explanation of there worth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably registers on the WMI events raised by the windows system itself.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, at the moment I have a crash in one of my applications and looking at the call stack I see a lot of mentions of the eventlog in the thread where the exception is raised, eg System.Diagnostics.EventLog.get_OldestEntryNumber() and System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CompletionCallback(System.Object)

Comment: I just searched some more info about it and it does interact with WMI through classes of the System.Management namespace.

Comment: Cheers for your help ChristopherS, any chance you could paste in any of the links you found here?